# Why don't the unmodifiable methods from Collections class, create collections with new elements?

Tags: java, list, collections, unmodifiable

Suppose there is this code:

```
List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(modifiableList);
System.out.println(unmodifiableList);
modifiableList.remove("1");
modifiableList.remove("3");
System.out.println(unmodifiableList);
```

it prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2]
```

If changing the second line to

```
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                                       new ArrayList<String>(modifiableList));
```

it works as expected. 
The question is why doesn't the `UnmodifiableList` inner class from Collections (and all the other unmodifiable classes) from there create a fresh copy of the original list, as does the constructor of `ArrayList` for example in order to really make it unmodifiable?

Edit: I understand what the code does; my question is why was it implemented this way? Why does the constructor from the UnmodifiableList (inner class from Collections) behave like the constructor of ArrayList in creating a fresh copy of the underlying array? Why a modifiable collection (ArrayList) copies the whole content while an unmodifiable collection doesn't?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun I understand what the code does; see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the *purpose* of the methods is to create an unmodifiable *view* on an existing collection. That's the documented behaviour, and in many cases it's exactly what you want - it's much more efficient than copying all the data, for example... or you want to hand callers collections which *will* reflect any changes you want to make, but without allowing them to make changes.

If you want an immutable *copy* of the data (or at least the references...) then just create a copy and then create an immutable view over the top of it - just as you are.

So basically, you can easily create either a view or a copy-and-view, based on `Collections.unmodifiable*` themselves performing the view operation. So we have two orthogonal operations:

- Create a copy (e.g. via the constructor)
- Create a view (via `Collections.unmodifiable*`)

Those operations can be composed very easily. If `Collections.unmodifiable*` actually performed a "copy only" then we'd require other operations in order to *just* make a view. If you accept that both options are useful in different situations, making them composable gives lots of flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple efficiency. Copying all of the elements of a collection could be very time-consuming, particularly if the collection being wrapped has some sort of magic going on like JPA lazy-loading, and requires extra memory. Wrapping the underlying collection as-is is a trivial operation that imposes no additional overhead. In the case where the developer really does want a separate copy (unmodifiable or not), it's very easy to create it explicitly. (I tend to use Guava `Immutable*` for this.)

Comment: Actually copying the elements is not that time consuming since it could use `Arrays.copy()` which uses something like `memcpy()` that is O(1) not O(n).

Comment: @m3th0dman Not in the general case. That might work for `ArrayList` specifically, but lots of `List` implementations aren't backed by arrays, and some (generators) might not even exist in the usual sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that unmodifiableList returns a "unmodifiable **view**" of provided list. So the list itself stays at it is (it can be still modified), only its "unmodifiable view" is unmodifiable. You can think of it as of SQL tables and views --- you can run DML scripts on tables and it will be reflected on related views. As to ArrayList --- it's backed by... an array, so it's implementation feature, that it copies elements from provided source list (which doesn't have to be backed by an array actually). Does it answer your question?